# options3d isn´t loading while using Highcharts in a custom Visual in power bi

Tags: highcharts, powerbi

Im using Highcharts in a custom visual in Power-bi... I have a Problem, without any Errors or Exceptions, that the 3D piechart isn't loading as 3D only 2D chart.

If you know what possibly could be the error,
maybe you can tell me.

here is what i did

```
        chart:{
         backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
          type: 'pie',
          options3d: {
              enabled: true,
              alpha: 45,}
      },
```

am i missing something ?
kind regards :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that by omitting the [plotOptions.pie.depth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.depth) the chart made 2D because there is no thickness set and the default is 0.

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      depth: 25,
    }
  },
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/23vkwe1j/

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.depth

Comment: the depth is set with "45", i followed a demo on the highchart webside! https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie-donut

Comment: Is the highcharts-3d.js module file loaded? This could also be the reason why 3d options are not working.

Comment: the 3d.js file is loaded and im still without any 3d pie...

Comment: Without an error in Highcharts, it is difficult to say more.

Comment: i got it i loaded the highchart like this
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import Highcharts3D from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d'
but forgot to do 
Highcharts3D(Highcharts)